# meta_query fails to compare on values containing apostrophes

Tags: wp-query, meta-query

I have WP Query and I am simply comparing by the meta value by =

My value contains town names, and seems to work great for the majority of names.

However some names contain apostrophes... **Madonna dell'olmo**

And the meta values with apostrophes fail to work.

This is my query...

```
$dealerResults = new WP_Query(array(
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'post_type'     => 'dealer',
    'meta_query'    => array(
        array(
               'key' => 'dealer_country',
               'value' => $ajaxCounty,
               'compare' => '='
        ),
        array(
               'key' => 'dealer_location',
               'value' => $ajaxTown,
               'compare' => '='
        )
    )      
));
```

I am passing the from a option value through some jquery function and ajax.

```
foreach($value as $town){
    echo "<option class=\"$county_class\" value=\"$town\">$town</option>";
}
```

-

```
dealerResults = function () {
    var county = $('#dealer-county').val(),
        town = $('#dealer-town').val(),
        wp_nonce = '<?php echo wp_create_nonce("dealer_search");?>';
    if(county != 0 && town != 0){
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>?r='+Math.random(),
            data: { varCounty : county, varTown : town, action: 'dealer_search', nonce: wp_nonce },
            success: function(data){
                $(".dealer-wrapper").remove();
                $("#dealer-results").append(data);      
            }
        });
    }
}
```

-

```
$ajaxCounty = $_POST['varCounty'];
$ajaxTown = $_POST['varTown'];
```

My question is how can I get the query to work for my meta values which contain apostrophes?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WordPress adds slashes to the REQUEST/GET/POST superglobals, if I'm not mistaken. Try this change:

```
$ajaxCounty = stripslashes( $_POST['varCounty'] );
$ajaxTown = stripslashes( $_POST['varTown'] );
```

[Related Trac ticket.](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/21767)

Comment: Duuuude.. you rock! Thank you for your help. Instant fix.